# How to disable BACKKEY when an alertbox is called

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which alert box is called on click of a button.
I want that when alert box is displayed it should not disappear without answering to it. Not even by pressing BACK KEY . Only when button on alert box is pressed it should act only then otherwise not.
Thank you please reply soon Urgent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myAlertBox.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: I assume you're using an AlertDialog for this.

Comment: Maybe you should considering accepting the answer if it helped you then.

Comment: http://www.androidfordev.blogspot.in/  here is the code i am using. ho to disable backkey on alert please help me fr this.Thankyou

Comment: you can put builder.setCancelable(false);

Comment: add it below builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog");// Set the Title of Alert Dialog

Answer (score -1):

Hi write your code inside this method

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setOnCancelListener (DialogInterface.OnCancelListener onCancelListener)
```

or

```
setCancelable(boolean)
```

Comment: once diaolog box is opened and back pressed, control will never listen inside onBackPressed.

Comment: guys tell whats the easiest nd best method

Comment: irrelevent, please remove your answer.